# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in heightForRowAtIndexPath iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm working on an application where I have a custom subclass of UITableViewCell. I want to make the cell's height dynamic based on the text inside it. I try do do that in my heightForRowAtIndexPath method. But I'm having some issues, the following code causes and EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2 address=0xb7ffffcc) error.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    PostCell *cell = (PostCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGSize postTextSize;
    if (![cell.postText.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        postTextSize = [cell.postText.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cell.postText.frame.size.width, 200)];
    } else {
        postTextSize = CGSizeMake(cell.postText.frame.size.width, 40);
    }

    return postTextSize.height + cell.userName.frame.size.height + 10;
}
```

If I instead have:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    return 100;
}
```

It works.

It seems to be crashing on this line: `PostCell *cell = (PostCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`, and I don't know why. I have tried to build clean and reset the simulator, but neither worked. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the problem. It turns out that calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath` causes `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to be called recursively. Here is an extract of the stack backtrace after the 3 recursion steps:

```
frame #0: 0x000042d0 DocInteraction`-[DITableViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 48 at DITableViewController.m:262
frame #1: 0x0054f688 UIKit`-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 3437
frame #2: 0x0055040f UIKit`-[UITableViewRowData(UITableViewRowDataPrivate) _ensureSectionOffsetIsValidForSection:] + 144
frame #3: 0x00551889 UIKit`-[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 137
frame #4: 0x00553dac UIKit`-[UITableViewRowData globalRowsInRect:] + 42
frame #5: 0x003f82eb UIKit`-[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _visibleGlobalRowsInRect:] + 177
frame #6: 0x004001e6 UIKit`-[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 113
frame #7: 0x000042f2 DocInteraction`-[DITableViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 82 at DITableViewController.m:262
frame #8: 0x0054f688 UIKit`-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 3437
frame #9: 0x0055040f UIKit`-[UITableViewRowData(UITableViewRowDataPrivate) _ensureSectionOffsetIsValidForSection:] + 144
frame #10: 0x00551889 UIKit`-[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 137
frame #11: 0x00553dac UIKit`-[UITableViewRowData globalRowsInRect:] + 42
frame #12: 0x003f82eb UIKit`-[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _visibleGlobalRowsInRect:] + 177
frame #13: 0x004001e6 UIKit`-[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 113
frame #14: 0x000042f2 DocInteraction`-[DITableViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 82 at DITableViewController.m:262
frame #15: 0x0054f688 UIKit`-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 3437
frame #16: 0x0055040f UIKit`-[UITableViewRowData(UITableViewRowDataPrivate) _ensureSectionOffsetIsValidForSection:] + 144
frame #17: 0x00551889 UIKit`-[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 137
frame #18: 0x003ff66d UIKit`-[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 119
frame #19: 0x003ff167 UIKit`-[UITableView reloadData] + 764
```

Finally the program crashes. On my Simulator this happens when the back trace is about 57000 levels deep.

---

**Old answer** (not wrong, but does not explain the
EXC_BAD_ACCESS):

The problem is that

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

returns `nil` for rows that are currently not visible. A table view allocates only so many cells that are required to display the currently visible rows. The cells are reused when you scroll the table view.

But `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called for *all* cells of the table view before any row is displayed.

As a consequence, you should not get the text from the table view cells to compute the height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. You should get the text from your data source instead.

Comment: By what mechanism does that method returning nil cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: @grahamparks: Good question! I have tried to reproduce the problem and added the information to my answer.

Comment: @Anders: You are welcome. - It was interesting to find out the exact cause for the problem, motivated by grahamparks comment.

Comment: thanks @MartinR for investigating. can you please edit the answer so that the recursion problem is described on top. returning nil is expected, and should not cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS. i almost did miss your added and important recursion analysis.

Answer (score 7):

`tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, before a cell is displayed, the height needs to be calculated first.

you should get `text` from your data source, not from `cell`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and came across, just to share what I do now which works well for me

```
CGFloat mycell_height;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    mycell_height = cell.frame.size.height;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return mycell_height; //assuming all cells are the same
}
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for this and new to iOS programming like me :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should call UITableViewDataSource method for getting cell for indexPath instead of cellForRowAtIndexPath: method of UITableView because at the moment when tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath: first time called there are no any cells in tableView.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PostCell *cell = (PostCell *)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGSize postTextSize;
    if (![cell.postText.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    postTextSize = [cell.postText.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cell.postText.frame.size.width, 200)];
    } else {
        postTextSize = CGSizeMake(cell.postText.frame.size.width, 40);
    }

    return postTextSize.height + cell.userName.frame.size.height + 10;
}
```

It works and no causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

Comment: It works for me, but it means UITableViewDataSource method works before cells are created in tableview, right? @ninjaproger

Answer (score -1):

SWIFT:

Use this to know when the tables have loaded:

```
extension UITableView {
    func reloadData(completion: ()->()) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0, animations: { self.reloadData() })
            { _ in completion() }
    }
}
```

Create a boolean value

```
var tables_loaded = Bool(false)
```

Then in viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.reloadData {
    tables_loaded = true
    // call functions or other stuff regarding table manipulation.
    // tableView.beginUpdates()
    // tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

then in

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            if tables_loaded {
                let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                 // Do your magic here!
             }

}
```

Comment: Not related, but `Bool(false)` seems useless: `false` is correct and Swift can infer its type. I'm interested as to why you would setup a `var` with the `Bool` initialiser?

Comment: @vrwim Because I'm a noob at Swift. =)