# Is there any reason why we don't simply declare cellForRowAtIndexPath like this:

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode4.5

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}
```

What would be the disadvantage?

I changed that from

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the first is legal Objective-C syntax.

Comment: (And I'm not sure either one is a good idea.)

Comment: What does this question have to do with declaring the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: @HotLicks The first one is fine (syntactically). `UITableView` has a method to directly get a cell like that.

Comment: @rmaddy -- OK, that makes sense -- two different methods on different classes.  At first glance it appears that the OP is trying to mix property syntax with regular method call syntax.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652761/exc-bad-access-in-heightforrowatindexpath-ios/12653203#12653203.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rmaddy points out, you can't use the first version because `-[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` can cause the table view to send you `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` again, resulting in infinite recursion.

If you are using a static set of cells, with one cell preallocated for each row of the table, then the second version is fine.

If you are dynamically creating cells for rows, the second version will end up draining your table view's reuse queue and then creating another cell for every row, because `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns an autoreleased object.  None of these cells will be deallocated until the end of the run loop, so in addition to the time cost of creating and destroying all of these cells, you're also using memory proportional to the number of rows in your table.  If you want to do it that way, and you have a lot of rows, you might want to use an explicit autorelease pool:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    @autoreleasepool {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell.bounds.size.height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would want to get a cell from the table like you do in the 1st bit of code. But in this case you can't. If you try, you will end up with a recursive call between `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

If you must get a cell from the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, you must NOT ask the table for the cell.

Comment: As rob pointed out, when you ask the table for the cell, the table first tries to get the cell's height. When it tries to get the height, you ask the table for the cell. This goes on until the stack overflows and the app crashes.

Comment: @SharenEayrs The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method returns a cell if the row is visible and nil if the row is not visible.  To figure out which rows are visible, the table view has to know the height of each cell.

Comment: That seems pretty silly. Why does it need to know the height of the cell first before knowing whether it's visible? It can ask for a row that might be visible, compute height, and move on to next row and stuff.