# How do I change the height of a table cell that has already loaded?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, heightforrowatindexpath

Currently I have webviews loading in customized uitableview cells.  The problem is the web views have variable sizes.  In webViewDidFinishLoad I am able to set the size of the web view based on the actual size of the html document just fine.  My problem is the table cells which have already had their height set in heightForRowAtIndexPath before the web views having finished loading.  How can I change the height of a table cell after it has already been loaded?

Ideally I feel like I should be able to use some line of code like this.

```
cellW.frame = cellW.cellWebView.frame;
```

However I don't seem to have access to cell information in heightForRowAtIndexPath.  I've felt like I've explained the situation fairly well, but any code you think I should post I can put up here.  I've tried a lot things (so there comments and failed attempts at this everywhere), but the main issue is I can't seem to access cell information in the right places such as heightForRowAtIndexPath.  If I could even set cell information somehow in webViewDidFinishLoad, I could simply set the frame of the cell where I am also setting the frame size of the web view.

Below is the setup for my table cell subclass.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DefinitionsAndConstants.h"

@interface UITableViewCellWebView : UITableViewCell
{
    UIWebView *cellWebView;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *cellWebView;
@end
```

Here is what I have tried last trying to use part Gavin's code.  But of course there is no way to set the table cell now that I've gotten out because cellForRowAtIndexPath is not assignable.

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViews {
    [webViews stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"twitterfy()"];
    [webViews stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('tweettext').innerHTML=tweet"];
    NSString* h = [webViews stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getDocHeightMax()"];
    int height = [h intValue];
    webViews.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, height);

    NSString* i = [webViews stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return indexPath"];
    int ii = [i intValue];
    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ii inSection:0];

    UITableViewCellWebView *tableCell = (UITableViewCellWebView *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];

    if (tableCell) {
        tableCell.frame = webViews.frame;
    }

    NSLog(@"Got height from webview %d", height);
}
```

Comment: I did find other questions related to this, but none of them seem to deal with dynamic cell heights.

Comment: Where are you loading your webviews?  If you just do it in `viewDidLoad`, it should be done loading before you draw the tables, right?  Sorry if that's a dumb question - I haven't used webviews before.

Comment: The web view load there, but they don't finish rendering content until webViewDidFinishLoad after heightForRowAtIndexPath has already executed.  So the height of the content isn't computed until webViewDidFinishLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up a mutable array to read heights from.  In `viewDidLoad`, you'll have to assign some starting values (probably just a bunch of `@"44.0"`, it doesn't really matter, it won't be used for much yet).  In your `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, just return the number from that array.  Then in `webViewDidFinishLoad`, replace the heights in the array with the height you actually need for that cell (the `NSString *h` in the code you posted, I believe), and call `reloadData` on your table view.  `reloadData` will hit `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, which will look at the heights array, which now has the actual height needed for that cell, so everything should be shiny.

Comment: I like the idea and I just tried it, but as I suspected reloadData redraws the cell and causes the web view to render again, causing an infinite loop.  Since web view only renders when a cell is visible scrolling down further causes an even more insane infinite loop.  The views look for the most part correct, but is choppy until the inevitable crash from the infinite loop.

Comment: I guess I will probably need to say something like, don't reloadData when the proper row in the array is already filled.  I'll test around some more and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Caimen: Hm, do you need to redraw the webviews in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?  Is it something that can change as the user interacts with it?  I would be temped to just build all the cells in `viewDidLoad`, put them into an array, and just pull the cell out of that array for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, instead of using `reuseIdentifier`s.  It seems the more experience I get with table views, the more I like the idea of building the cells once and then being done with it (instead of building them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as I need them).

Comment: I've got the infinite loop stopped now simply checked the correct node in the array and not reloading the view when the value has been set.  There is currently some unexplainable white space displaying, but I'm fairly certain you've put me on the right track.  I'll probably check this as correct tomorrow once I'm completely confident the solution is working properly.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: didnt understant, how you solved the problem with infinite looop?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this for your heightForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *tableCell = (MyTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (tableCell) {
        return tableCell.cellWebView.frame.size.height;
    }

    return 44;
}
```

This way, if the table cell is visible, it'll set the height according to the height of the embedded web view, otherwise it'll use a default height. In order to make the table view refresh the height of the cell, you'll have to call the following once the web view is sized properly:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

That won't make it reload the cells, which could screw things up for you, it'll just make it check the heights again, and the cell height will animate to the new height.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need.  

However

UITableViewCellWebView *tableCell = (UITableViewCellWebView *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; keeps returning EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I'm still new to some of this, but I'm guessing this is a sign I have some deeper problem I need to solve first.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `UITableViewCellWebView` your `UITableViewCell` subclass, or is that a subclass of `UIWebView`?

Comment: It is the UITableViewCell subclass.  I posted my subclass in the question.

Comment: Apparently calling cellForRowAtIndexPath: inside heightForRowAtIndexPath: causes it to recursively call heightForRowAtIndexPath:, so that's why it crashes. Details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652761/exc-bad-access-in-heightforrowatindexpath-ios

Comment: Keep separately a table of the heights calculated for the web views at each index path, and use that to get the height here instead.