# Dynamic UITableViewCell height for a cell that contains a UIWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

What I'm trying to do is load some HTML resource files in to UITableView cells. I wanted to adjust the cell heights depend on the content size of the UIWebView. Following is some of my test codes.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableCellID";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSString *htmlFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:htmlFileName ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [cell.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

    return cell;
}
```

If I describe my CustomTableViewCell.xib, it has a UIWebView inside the Content View and UIWebView has following constraints given.

```
ContentView.Bottom = WebView.Bottom + 8
ContentView.Top = WebView.Top +8
ContentView.Leading = WebView.Leading + 8
ContentView.Trailing = WebView.Trailing + 8
```

HTML fils has no JavaScript or CSS content. Simple as below.

```
<html>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
        <p>eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee eeeee</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now my out put is like below image.

[image]

As I explained at top, my web pages doesn't contain any JavaScript. So I may not able to use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method to return the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the height of a table cell that has already loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666405/how-do-i-change-the-height-of-a-table-cell-that-has-already-loaded)

Comment: I believe that computing the height of a webview after it has loaded will be easier and then letting the cell adjust based on the webView's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my own solution. But thanks all the others who commented on this question and open my mind in different paths. So here what I did.

First added a UIWebViewDelegate to my ViewController class

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate> {
```

Then loading HTML pages and adding delegate is done inside following method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableCellID";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.webView.delegate = self;
    cell.webView.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    NSString *htmlFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:htmlFileName ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [cell.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

    return cell;
}
```

After web view is loaded, calculate the size that fits to it's content and after all web views are loaded, I reload table data like below.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    if (webView.tag == 0) {
        [cellHeightMutArray removeAllObjects];
    }

    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

    [cellHeightMutArray insertObject:@(fittingSize.height) atIndex:webView.tag];

    if (((webView.tag + 1) == dataArray.count) && !reloadedTableViewAfterLoadingWebContent) {

        reloadedTableViewAfterLoadingWebContent = YES;
        _tableView.hidden = NO;

        [_tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Then I adjust the height of the cell (which was the main issue that I had)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (cellHeightMutArray.count > 0) {

        return [[cellHeightMutArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];
    }

    return 44;
}
```

This is my solution and it works perfectly in iPhones and iPads.

But I had different issue when I run it with more complex user interface in iPads which is in my real project. I'll update this if my solutions for those issue related to this question.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    arrOfHTMLList= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic1 setObject:@"0" forKey:@"height"];
    [dic1 setObject:@"aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa" forKey:@"htmlString"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic1 setObject:@"0" forKey:@"height"];
    [dic1 setObject:@"abababababbabababababab ababab bababa  ababababb" forKey:@"htmlString"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic1 setObject:@"0" forKey:@"height"];
    [dic1 setObject:@"sdajdkjas dkasjkhd jkashjkd sakjhdkj askjdaksh dksajkdkjsah djkasjkhd kjsahjkd asjkhdk jasjkdhaskj" forKey:@"htmlString"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic4 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic1 setObject:@"0" forKey:@"height"];
    [dic1 setObject:@"sdajdkjas dkasjkhd jkashjkd sakjhdkj askjdaksh dksajkdkjsah djkasjkhd kjsahjkd asjkhdk jasjkdhaskj" forKey:@"htmlString"];

    [arrOfHTMLList addObject:dic1];
    [arrOfHTMLList addObject:dic2];
    [arrOfHTMLList addObject:dic3];
    [arrOfHTMLList addObject:dic4];
    }


-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    UIWebView *webView = (UIWebView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSString *myHTML = arrOfHTMLList[indexPath.section][@"htmlString"];
    [webView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
    webView.delegate = self;
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth,cell.frame.size.height);
return cell;
}


-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    for (UIView *parent=[webView superview];parent!=nil ;parent=[parent superview] )
    {
        if([parent isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)parent;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath=[_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            int height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
            [[arrOfHTMLList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",height] forKey:@"height"];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        }
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height = [arrOfHTMLList[indexPath.section][@"height"] intValue];
    return height;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this doesn't work because a web view's frame doesn't adapt to its html content right away :) - only async

Comment: @Daij-Djan, this should be working, because it calls back the "webView.scrollView.contentSize.height" instead of the frame's height.

Answer (score 0):

the main issue is to get a web view's frame to adapt to its html content right away :)
and THAT only happens after it asynchronously loaded the content!

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView  *)aWebView {
     //TODO: update the table's height for the cell for the webview
}
```

a drop-in solution I wrote is a custom UITableViewCell subclass that has a webview and informs a delegate to reload the table:

https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDUtils/tree/master/objC/DDUtils-IOS/ui/M42WebviewTableViewCell%20%5Bios%5D

the most important piece of code is:

```
- (UITableViewCell  *)tableView:(UITableView  *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
    M42WebviewTableViewCell *cell = _loadedCells[@(indexPath.row)];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[M42WebviewTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

        NSString *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        cell.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.delegate = self;
        [cell setHtml:object AndBaseURL:nil];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView  *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
    //if a cell isnt ready, it wont be there and the method will return 0
    M42WebviewTableViewCell *cell = _loadedCells[@(indexPath.row)];
    return cell.height;
}

#pragma mark - M42WebviewTableViewCellDelegate

- (void)tableCellDidLoadContent:(M42WebviewTableViewCell *)cell {
    if (!_loadedCells) {
        _loadedCells = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    [_loadedCells setObject:cell forKey:@(cell.tag)];

    //only refresh sizes of rows
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```