# Get UITableViewCell from indexPath not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i was trying to updated the cell item while updating the height of the cell but its not working.

```
[_tblBillHistory beginUpdates];
[_tblBillHistory endUpdates];
```

these method i have used to updated the cell height

Err- > EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x7fff5b4daf98)
this error message getting for cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Nslog also printing the selected row correctly. any idea??? thank you.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if((selectedPath!=nil ) & ([indexPath isEqual:selectedPath])) {
        NSLog(@"%ld",indexPath.row);
        UITableViewCell *tempCell = [_tblBillHistory cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        UIStackView *stkItems=(UIStackView *)[tempCell viewWithTag:8];

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
            [btn setTitle:@"test button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [stkItems addArrangedSubview:btn];
        }

        return 700;
    }

    return 250;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this

[EXC_BAD_ACCESS in heightForRowAtIndexPath iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652761/exc-bad-access-in-heightforrowatindexpath-ios)

Comment: i think i found the solution.. i have to call the cellForRowAtIndexPath method before i call the beginUpdates and endUpadates methods. but i don't know what was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method is not good place to update cell's components.
If you want to add element to the cell you can create it at any other methods, for example:

```
- tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

*heightForRowAtIndexPath* may be called many times (every reloadData or animation block).

You should divide your code, in heightForRowAtIndexPath you should only  calculate height without request the cell (because the tableView not have cells in this method). 
Adding or removing elements to the cell you can create in the *didSelectMethod* (but more better solution move this code to the cell or create a custom class for selected cell):

```
 - tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: Yes. i think thats was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace following line

```
UITableViewCell *tempCell = [_tblBillHistory cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

with this one

```
UITableViewCell *tempCell = [self tableView:_tblBillHistory cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This will stop recursive call as this is calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as a function not as data source of table view....