# rectForRowAtIndexPath crashing with defined indexPath in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The following code is crashing at

> currentCellRect = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths[0])

But only sometimes.

```
public func showCellScrollCount(animated:Bool) {
    self.tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    self.tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "dragging", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
}

override public func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    switch (keyPath, object) {

    case (.Some("contentOffset"), _):
        self.updateScrollPosition()
    default:
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}

func updateScrollPosition() {

    let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
    var currentCellRect:CGRect?
    if let indexPaths = indexPaths {
        if indexPaths.count > 0 {
            currentCellRect = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths[0])
            scrollCountView.currentScrollCountNum = indexPaths[0].row
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes with "BAD_ACCESS". Does anyone have any idea why?

[image]

[image]

...

[image]

EDIT: Is it possible it's happening because I'm calling tableView.reloadData() right before I add observers, and the call isn't finished yet?

Comment: Debug console message?  Stack trace?

Comment: Look to this solution may be its related to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652761/exc-bad-access-in-heightforrowatindexpath-ios

Comment: No debug console message, added some screenshots of the stack trace if they're helpful, I don't know what to make of them @PhillipMills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Your code works fine since I added it to my tableView controller and called `showCellScrollCount` func once. Where you call `showCellScrollCount`, do you call it multiple times? It can be problem if so.

**Update 3**

here is the problem:

```
public var totalScrollCountNum = 0 {
    didSet {
        scrollCountView.totalScrollCountNum = totalScrollCountNum
        showCellScrollCount(false)
    }
}
```

move `showCellScrollCount(false)` to initializers

Comment: Also I posted some screenshots of the stack trace, it seems all the calls are already happening on the main thread?

Comment: @Nirri Yes, different threads not the point here. Problem is somwhere in hidden parts of your code

Comment: https://github.com/xtrinch/MRTableViewCellCountScrollIndicator Although I very rarely experience the forementioned crash with the example project you can also see in the following link, I'm having problems in a larger project I'm trying to add it to, it crashes 80% of the time

Comment: About Update 3: Why is that the problem?

Comment: Tried it anyway, still crashing with the same stack trace

Comment: @Nirri because you adding observer multiple times, 2 time at least. But 2 times is not really problem, I thought there was recursive adding. I have build and run your project at iOS 9.3 iPhone 6 simulator, there is no such error, all works fine.

Comment: Thanks that gives me an idea where to start, it seems it's a problem with my  other project initializing my class with the same tableView way too many times, and it's not a problem in the code I posted up there.