# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when inside heightForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to create expandable UITableViewCells using the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! feedBaseCell

    if cell.expandButton.isExpanded == true {
        return 128
    } else {
        return 64
    }
    return 64
}
```

`.isExpanded` is a custom property of feedBaseCell. When I run this code, the line `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! feedBaseCell` gets a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. How can I check the `.isExpanded` property and return the height based on whether or not it is true or false? Why is my code not working?

EDIT: Code for both `cellForRowAt` and `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedBaseCell") as! feedBaseCell

    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    cell.expandButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.expandButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.expandTheCell(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.expandButton)

    return cell
}
```

Here is the `expandTheCell` method:

```
func expandTheCell(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isExpanded == false {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            sender.transform = sender.transform.rotated(by: .pi/2)
            sender.isExpanded = true
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            sender.transform = sender.transform.rotated(by: -.pi/2)
            sender.isExpanded = false
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `cell.isExpanded` instead of `cell.expandButton.isExpanded` if `.isExpanded` is a custom property of `feedBaseCell` ?

Comment: you can opt for UIStackView to design your cells. Cells would maintain their height according to views that are visible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652761/exc-bad-access-in-heightforrowatindexpath-ios) ques.

Comment: Add your `expandTheCell` method to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Never call `cellForRow(at:)` from within `heightForRowAt`. It causes infinite recursion because the table view tries to get the cell's height when you ask for the cell.

If you really, really need to get a cell to calculate its height, directly call your view controller's dataSource method `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method instead of the table view's `cellForRow(at:)` method.

But in this case you don't need the cell. You should be storing the expanded state of each row in your data source data, not in the cell itself. Look at that data, not the cell, to determine the height in your `heightForRowAt` method. And of course you will need this state information in your `cellForRowAt` data source method so you can set the cell's state there since cells get reused as you scroll the table view.

Comment: How do I look at the data?

Comment: I'm talking about the data used by your table view's data source.

Comment: Right, how do I access the data in my table views data source?

Comment: You already are. You access it in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method and the `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: How can I determine the height outside of the `heightForRowAt` function then? I'm not sure I'm following you...

Comment: That's not what I said at all. You still use `heightForRowAt` to return the height. You just don't need the cell inside `heightForRowAt`. You are currently only getting the cell in `heightForRowAt` so you can look at the cell's `isExpanded` property. My answer is telling you that you need to be keeping track of the expanded state of each row in your data model, not in the cell.

Comment: How do I keep track of the expanded state in the data model? I still have to have an if statement in `heightForRowAt` though right? What would be the variables in the if statement?

Comment: Yes, you still need an `if` statement. The variables are up to you and how you implement your data used for your data source.

Comment: What do you mean implement the data in my dataSource? Can you write some code or give me an example?

Comment: Look at your own existing code for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` for an example.

Comment: I added the code to my edit. Even after looking at it I'm still confused as to what to do.

Comment: That explains the confusion. You have no data. You have hardcoded 3 cells with no information of any kind in them.

Comment: Oh, I have always done it like this. How do I add information to my cells?